# D3 - Updating and clearing chart's on click

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to implement this simple dashboard http://bl.ocks.org/diethardsteiner/3287802 to work with my backend. The problem is that the backend is not always providing the same amount of "categories" so the bar charts are not working as desired. I've created a fiddle with sample data and the problem occurs after clicking different "Groups" in pie chart https://jsfiddle.net/7t67yxfk/1/.

```
    function up(d, i) {
            /* update bar chart when user selects piece of the pie chart */
            //updateBarChart(dataset[i].category);
            updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));           
}
```

How can I clear the data from the bar chart and only show the bar charts and labels that are available for each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart does not remove the extra elements that exist, and append if need be.
I updated your [plunk](https://jsfiddle.net/7t67yxfk/4/) to apply the enter-update-exit pattern:

```
var plot = d3.select("#barChartPlot")
  .datum(currentDatasetBarChart)
  .select('g.plot');

  var dataBound = plot.selectAll("rect")
      .data(currentDatasetBarChart);
    dataBound.exit()
      .remove();
    dataBound.enter().append('rect');
    dataBound.transition()
         .duration(750)
         .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return xScale(i);
         })
         .attr("width", width / currentDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)   
         .attr("y", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.measure);
         })  
         .attr("height", function(d) {
            return height-yScale(d.measure);
         })
         .attr("fill", colorChosen);
```

This basically means that every time the selection changes, you need to reselect all your rectangles, remove the useless ones, add new ones, and then update all properties.

I also added a `plot` class to the group containing the rectangles to be able to manipulate them in the appropriate place.

As side notes, I would suggest to:

- use an `axis` instead of manipulating the labels yourself
- create one svg group per bar, containing the rect and the text, and translate that complete group
- use d3 v4

Comment: Thank you for your help Hugues and your suggestions. I already started to change the graph to d3v4 version, but faced some new problems, so will leave that a bit later. One question: In your updated version of my plunk, do you know why the bar chart is losing the y-labels after viewing Group with less categories? For example, if you click "Group 4" and review "Group 2" after that, only the first bar has the y-label.

Comment: Lines 424 and 425 remove extra labels. I did not put an `append` there. You need to add `labels.enter().append('text').classed("yAxis", true);`